# Chain rule problem from multivariate calc

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $u : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be a smooth function and define $v : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ by
>   $$v(x,y) = u(ax + by, cx + dy).$$
>   Compute $v_{xx}$ and $v_{yy}$.

My attempt: I believe I have been able to compute the first partials, but I am unsure I did the second partials correctly.

Let $u$ be a function of $w$ and $z$. Then
$$v_x = au_w + cu_z$$
$$v_y = bu_v + du_z$$
Now
$$v_{xx} = a(u_w)_x + c(u_z)_x = a(au_{ww}) + c(au_{zz})$$
$$v_{yy} = b(u_v)_y + d(u_z)_y = b(bu_{vv}) + c(cu_{vv})$$

Comment: @QuinnGreicius your answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't introduce new variable names $w$ and $z$ unless you are really working with these "auxiliary coordinates". On the other hand I'm not happy with Quinn Greicius' suggestion either, since it implies that the letter $x$ has two different meanings: (i) it is the name of the first variable of the outer function $u$, and (ii) it is the name of the first "working variable" of the function $v$.

Instead I propose that you just number the variables of the outer function $u$ and write
$$v_x= a u_{.1}+c u_{.2},\qquad v_y=b u_{.1}+d u_{.2}\ .$$
If $u\in C^2$ we can proceed and then obtain, e.g.,
$$v_{xx}=a(au_{.11}+c u_{.12})+c(a u_{.21}+c u_{.22})=a^2 u_{.11}+2ac u_{.12}+c^2 u_{.22}\ ,$$
whereby the partial derivatives of $u$ have to evaluated at $(ax+by,cx+dy)$. This differs from what you have obtained.